# My facebook page is still not visible to the people

Tags: facebook

Last Thursday I created my facebook page, but till now it's not visible on FB search.

I think that my page settings are all correct.

[image: facebook page settings]

Should I wait another day or two? Or there is some kind of problem with my settings?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s not related to programming

Comment: afaik it takes a while to show up in the search. that does not matter it´s not visible to people, so the title is misleading.